# How to create a 3D chart in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

My application displays the result of Students in graphical form.The graph is a column graph which contains the subject names and marks.
Below is how my graph is created:

```
string zz={ "Subject1", "Subject2", "Subject3", "TOTAL" };
```

**kk** contains subject marks.

```
var mychart= new Chart(width: 1000, height: 800, theme: ChartTheme.Blue)
            .AddSeries(
                chartType: "column",
                legend: "StudentResult",
                xValue: zz,
               yValues: kk)
              .Write();
```

I want to show graph in 3D.
Im aware of **MS Chart**,but cant change my application.Can i do the 3D chart without **MS Chart/google chart.

If yes How? and if No then what changes should i make to implement ***MS Chart***

I tried:

```
var mychart= new Chart(width: 1000, height: 800, theme: ChartTheme.Vanilla3D)
```

but its not giving me the desired output.The color is too loud and aswell its truncating names of my subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using MS Chart, since u are using .net.  Download http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418

and run, view the example and code to find out what you can achieve and how to setup 3D chart. for sure you can define color for each series.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using theme of chart

```
  @{
        var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Vanilla3D )
            .AddTitle("Chart Title")
            .AddSeries(
                name: "ChartTitle",
                xValue: new[] {  "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5" },
                yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
            .Write();
    }
```

And then change colors.

```
    axisTitleTop: {     
       fill: '#000',     
       font: '11px Arial' 
    }, axisTitleLeft: { 
           fill: '#000',     
       font: '11px Arial' 
    }, axisTitleRight: { 
           fill: '#000',     
       font: '11px Arial' 
    }, axisTitleBottom: {     
       fill: '#000',     
       font: '11px Arial' 
    },labelTitle:{

      fill:"#B22222"
    }
```

Comment: Excellenet answer